# Design listbox in codebehind

Tags: windows-phone-7

I design Listbox in code behind. I would like to set listbox with orientation is horizontal. 
But I don't know set ItemsPanel in code. Can you help me ? Thanks. 
In xaml design I use :

```
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>

                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Beside I want to add another properties in listbox which not existed. ex : in xaml,I can add Grid.column = 1 in Listbox, but I don't know use it in code behind.

Comment: you can directly add stackpanel without add the item panel.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly add stackpanel without add the item panel.

```
listBox1 = new ListBox();  
  stackpanel stk = new stackpanel();  
  listbox1.items.add(stk);
```

for setting grid:

```
 var textBlock = new TextBlock { Text="mytext" };  
   Grid.SetColumn(textBlock, 1);  
   Grid.SetRow(textBlock, 1);  
   Grid.Children.Add(textBlock);
```